# Hmisc::latex function not working correctly when using both cellTexCmds and cgroup arguments (newer R/package version)

Tags: r, latex, hmisc

I'm trying to format a table for LaTeX using the `latex` function in the `Hmisc` package, using both the `cellTexCmds` argument to format specific cells, and the `cgroup`/`n.cgroup` arguments to produce header groupings.

The behaviour I'm expecting happens in R 2.15.0 with `Hmisc` version 3.12-2:

```
> table.data<-data.frame(a=1:3,b=4:6,c=3:5,d=8:10)
> tex.matrix<-matrix(rep("",12),nrow=3)
> tex.matrix[1,3]<-"\\color{red}"
> latex(table.data,cgroup=c("group1","group2"),n.cgroup=c(2,2),cellTexCmds=tex.matrix,file="")
% latex.default(table.data, cgroup = c("group1", "group2"), n.cgroup = c(2,      2), cellTexCmds = tex.matrix, file = "") 
%
\begin{table}[!tbp]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{lrrcrr}
\hline\hline
\multicolumn{1}{l}{\bfseries table.data}&\multicolumn{2}{c}{\bfseries group1}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{\bfseries }&\multicolumn{2}{c}{\bfseries group2}\tabularnewline
\cline{2-3} \cline{5-6}
\multicolumn{1}{l}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{a}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{b}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{c}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{d}\tabularnewline
\hline
   1&   $1$&   $4$&   &\\color{red}   $3$&   $ 8$\tabularnewline
   2&   $2$&   $5$&   &   $4$&   $ 9$\tabularnewline
   3&   $3$&   $6$&   &   $5$&   $10$\tabularnewline
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
```

with the `\color{red}` command in cell (1,3). In a newer version (R 3.2.0, `Hmisc` version 3.17-4) this happens:

```
> table.data<-data.frame(a=1:3,b=4:6,c=3:5,d=8:10)
> tex.matrix<-matrix(rep("",12),nrow=3)
> tex.matrix[1,3]<-"\\color{red}"
> latex(table.data,cgroup=c("group1","group2"),n.cgroup=c(2,2),cellTexCmds=tex.matrix,file="")
%latex.default(table.data, cgroup = c("group1", "group2"), n.cgroup = c(2,     2), cellTexCmds = tex.matrix, file = "")%
\begin{table}[!tbp]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{lrrcrr}
\hline\hline
\multicolumn{1}{l}{\bfseries table.data}&\multicolumn{2}{c}{\bfseries group1}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{\bfseries }&\multicolumn{2}{c}{\bfseries group2}\tabularnewline
\cline{2-3} \cline{5-6}
\multicolumn{1}{l}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{a}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{b}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{c}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{d}\tabularnewline
\hline
   1&   $1$&   $4$&   &   $3$&\\color{red}   $ 8$\tabularnewline
   2&   $2$&   $5$&   &   $4$&   $ 9$\tabularnewline
   3&   $3$&   $6$&   &   $5$&   $10$\tabularnewline
\hline
\end{tabular}\end{center}

\end{table}
```

The extra formatting is now in cell (1,4). Without the `cgroup` and `n.cgroup` arguments for the major header groupings it works fine in either version. Is this just a bug in the new version of the package or has there been some change that means this is the correct behaviour and if so how would I get the desired result (I can't see anything in the documentation that suggests there's been any change)?

Comment: Hi! I've tested with R3.4.2 and I can't reproduce the problem